# How can I explain Cloud Computing without technical jargon?

Tags: cloud

I need to explain Cloud Computing to someone without technical training or experience. Can you suggest any way that have worked well?

Also, some Internet Services are not strict Cloud Computing, but they says their serviecs are *Cloud (Online) Drive*, *Cloud (Online) Music*, or *Cloud (Internet) Smart TV*, how can I explain that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Computing in a nutshell is about leasing hardware or software through the internet on demand.